# Does Kanima's mythology match any historical stories/works or is it only written for Teen Wolf?

Tags: origin, teen-wolf-tv

In [Teen Wolf Season 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Wolf_%28season_2%29), a new creature called a Kanima appears, which is a part of the major plot line. My question is, is this Kanima creature all made up for the *Teen wolf* series, or is it inspired by any existing fictional work or historical story?

Comment: All searches for Kamina direct me back to Teen Wolf, so I suspect that the concept was indeed made up just for the show.

Comment: There is a South American novel called "[Canaima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canaima_%28novel%29)", by Gallegos. The title refers to a mythical beast of the jungle.

Comment: http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Kanima_Physiology i hope this can sort of help it gives a description of a part of the myth but i could not find anything history wise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [interview](http://www.assignmentx.com/2012/exclusive-interview-teen-wolf-showrunner-jeff-davis-talks-season-2-finale-and-season-3/) with *Teen Wolf* creator Jeff Davis, the Kanima is, at least loosely, based on South American mythology.  He says the original Kanima was a "were-jaguar" (that is, half-man, half-jaguar; named in analogy with "werewolf").  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Were-jaguar) on the were-jaguar suggests that it may have been inspired by a venomous toad thought to resemble a jaguar.  However, the *Teen Wolf* version is more like a reptile.  Davis says

> I ... saw CONAN THE BARBARIAN. And one indelible image that was left in my mind was the scene where James Earl Jones starts to transform into a gigantic snake.  That look stuck with me and that’s what we went for

So the name may come from South American mythology, but the appearance has a more modern origin.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up hearing the stories of the Canaima as told by my Native American grandmother and other people when I visited the village in Guyana South America.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the story and creature?

Comment: @AnkitSharma, According to Wiki, the Orinoco jungle is the main character and at the same time the reason behind all of the other characters' actions. Canaima represents a bitter struggle against caudillism. A film adaptation of the novel was made in 1945. The jungle basically represents the ideology of the author.

Answer (score -1):

In the belief system of the Carib tribes, Kanaima is an evil spirit that possesses people and causes them to turn into deadly animals and/or go into a murderous rage. Assassins, or Carib people seeking revenge for a slain relative, sometimes invited the Kanaima spirit into themselves by taking certain drugs or conducting certain magic rituals

Comment: Can you provide a reference to back up your answer?